# How to import Modules (.pan file) , Inverters (.ond file) and meteorological data from SolarGIS into PVLib?

Tags: python, pvlib

I am currently trying to create a PVlib project where I am attempting to import Solar modules .pan files and inverter .ond files provided to me but other than the `retrieve_sam` command. I am not seeing a capability to import existing .pan and .ond files from my laptop for PVlib to read the same.

Additionally, I used the IO Tool APIs to import meteorological data from PVGIS but when I already have existing data from SolarGIS, I am not sure how I can import it into the library from my laptop.

Appreciate the help coming over for this. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

pvlib doesn't currently have any functionality for reading PVsyst files, but some other people have made python code to do so, e.g. https://github.com/frivollier/pvsyst_tools.  Here is some relevant discussion from the pvlib google group: https://groups.google.com/g/pvlib-python/c/PDDic0SS6ao/m/Z-WKj7C6BwAJ

For reading your existing data files, if `pvlib.iotools` does not have a suitable function, you can always DIY using pandas (e.g. [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) or similar).  Most of the `iotools` functions use pandas under the hood anyway.  To give a more specific recommendation we'd need to see a snippet of your file to see exactly what format it is in.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue, I have some weather files with `.pvsyst` extensions (you can see the head of the file below) and I found it easier to just use the pandas.

First, change the extension of the file to `.csv`, then open the file and check if it has any comments or info lines. In my case, the files start with many comment lines and also one line with info regarding unit:

```
#TMY hourly data
#Standard format for importing hourly data in PVsyst
#Created from EnergyPlus Weather Converter version=2022.04.01
#WMO=105130Data Source=Custom-105130
#Site,Koln.Bonn.AP
#Country,DEU
#Data Source,Custom-105130 WMO=105130
#Time step,Hour
#Latitude,50.864
#Longitude,7.158
#Altitude,100
#Time Zone,1.00
Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,GHI,DHI,DNI,Tamb,WindVel,WindDir
,,,,,W/m2,W/m2,W/m2,deg.C,m/sec,�
2059,1,1,1,30,0,0,0,0.000,1.00,21
2059,1,1,2,30,0,0,0,0.000,1.00,120
```

This means I need to tell the pandas that the lines that start with `#` are comments and later drop the first index:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('weather.csv', comment='#')
print(df.head())


df = df.drop(0)
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
     Year  Month  Day  Hour  Minute   GHI   DHI   DNI   Tamb WindVel WindDir
0     NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN     NaN  W/m2  W/m2  W/m2  deg.C   m/sec       �
1  2059.0    1.0  1.0   1.0    30.0     0     0     0  8.000    3.00     250
2  2059.0    1.0  1.0   2.0    30.0     0     0     0  8.000    4.00     260
3  2059.0    1.0  1.0   3.0    30.0     0     0     0  8.000    4.00     240
4  2059.0    1.0  1.0   4.0    30.0     0     0     0  8.000    4.00     240

     Year  Month  Day  Hour  Minute GHI DHI DNI   Tamb WindVel WindDir
1  2059.0    1.0  1.0   1.0    30.0   0   0   0  8.000    3.00     250
2  2059.0    1.0  1.0   2.0    30.0   0   0   0  8.000    4.00     260
3  2059.0    1.0  1.0   3.0    30.0   0   0   0  8.000    4.00     240
4  2059.0    1.0  1.0   4.0    30.0   0   0   0  8.000    4.00     240
5  2059.0    1.0  1.0   5.0    30.0   0   0   0  8.000    4.00     240
```